# IIS Pool Stop issue in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, application-pool

i don't know where i am stuck, but whenever i created the object of one of the class from App_Code, my sites pool stops, i dont understand whats wrong, with that class, everything is straightforward.

i have BAL and DAL created under App_Code, when i create the object of BAL, the App_Pool Stops.

here is a the [BAL](http://gp.dev.asentechdev1.com/blLogic.txt)
and [DAL](http://gp.dev.asentechdev1.com/dlLogic.txt)

Please can anyone help me with this, i am stuck here for the last 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your event logs, you probably have a permission problem that is crashing the pool inside of your BAL/DAL.

1. Open Event Viewer by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start
   button, clicking Control Panel, clicking System and Security,
   clicking Administrative Tools, and then double-clicking Event
   Viewer.‌ Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an
   administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide
   confirmation.
2. Click the Error first, then check the Application event log.
3. Look for red error icons.

Comment: hi rick can you please further help me with how and what to check under event logs.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i checked there, there are no such errors related to app_pool stop, infact there are no errors, there are just warnings, and even they are not related, can you tell me is there any issues within the code.